# Caching on web services in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services

I want to add cache in all my web methods for a web service. But i don't know the right way to do it ...

Any ideas what can i do for this ? Thanks !

Here is my code ..

```
Dim _cache As Cache = New Cache()
<WebMethod>
Public Function GetAllSpeakers(SubSite As String, MyUsername As String, MyPassword As String) As String
    If ValidateUser(MyUsername, MyPassword) Then

        Dim cachedSpeakers As String
        cachedSpeakers = CStr(_cache("CacheSpeakers"))

        If (cachedSpeakers Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            Dim passWordEnc As SecureString = New SecureString()
            For Each c As Char In Password.ToCharArray()
                passWordEnc.AppendChar(c)
            Next

            Dim subContext As ClientContext = New ClientContext("url")
            subContext.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, passWordEnc)

            Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LibraryMethods.Methods.GetSpeakers(subContext))

            _cache.Insert("CacheSpeakers", json,
            Nothing, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0))

            Return json

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "ERROR: " & ex.InnerException.ToString
        End Try
    Else
        Return _cache("CacheSpeakers").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        Return "AUTHENTICATION FAILED"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some changes om my method and now cache working !!
I use HttpRuntime.Cache .

```
<WebMethod>
Public Function GetAllSpeakers(SubSite As String, MyUsername As String, MyPassword As String) As String
    If ValidateUser(MyUsername, MyPassword) Then

        If (HttpRuntime.Cache("CacheSpeakers") Is Nothing) Then
            Try
                Dim passWordEnc As SecureString = New SecureString()
                For Each c As Char In Password.ToCharArray()
                    passWordEnc.AppendChar(c)
                Next

                Dim subContext As ClientContext = New ClientContext("url")
                subContext.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, passWordEnc)

                Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LibraryMethods.Methods.GetSpeakers(subContext))


                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("CacheSpeakers", json, Nothing,
                Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, New TimeSpan(0, 30, 0),
                CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Nothing)

                Return json

            Catch ex As Exception
                Return "ERROR: " & ex.InnerException.ToString
            End Try
        Else
            Return HttpRuntime.Cache("CacheSpeakers").ToString()
        End If
    Else
        Return "AUTHENTICATION FAILED"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure what version of the .NET framework you are targeting. Its recommenced to use MemoryCache for .NET 4.0 and above. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications